# My "account balance" variable is not updated by the code

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, global-variables

This code basically just asks the user what to do, then, using 2 functions, it either adds or subtracts money from my actual variable. However, the variable is not updated by the code. I don't see why.

```
actbal =  (100);
confirm("Would you like to view account balance? Place a deposit? Or make a withdrawl? Press OK to continue!");

do
{

var v = "VIEW";
var d = "DEP";
var w = "WITH";

var cont1 = prompt('Type: "VIEW" , "DEP" , or "WITH" to do their respective comands');

if( v === cont1.substring(0))
{
    confirm("Your account balance is: " + actbal);

}
else if (d === cont1.substring(0))
{
    var depo = prompt("How much do you want to deposit?");
    var cat = parseFloat(depo);
     if(cat < 0)
    {
        alert("You cant Deposit a negative number...");
    }
    else
    {

    confirm("Your new account balance is: " + deposit(cat));
    //var actbal = actbal + cat;
    }

}
else if (w === cont1.substring(0))
{
    var With = prompt("How much do you want to withdrawl?");
    var dog = parseFloat(With);
    if(dog < 0)
    {
        alert("You cant Deposit a negative number...");
    }
    else
    {

    confirm("Your new account balance is: " + withdrawl(dog));
    }

}
else
{
    alert("You have not entered a command correctly!");

}
}
while
(
   confirm("Do you want to continue with your account?")
);


var deposit = function(cat)
{
    actbal = +actbal  +cat;
    return +actbal  +cat;




};

var withdrawl = function (dog)
{
    actbal = actbal - dog; 
    return actbal - dog; 

};
```

Comment: Why do you use `cont1.substring(0)` instead of just `cont1`?

Comment: Didn't you notice errors in the Javascript console when you were debugging this?

Comment: Hmm after removing the substring finder it does work. I wasnt expecting it to work that easily. I will change it to better simplify the code but I was not getting any errors in my code. My issue was, according to other posters (and proven by them) was my function declarations being placed incorrectly. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using javascript functions in a way that they are defined during parse-time instead of runtime.

Example:

```
function deposit(amt) {
    //do stuff here
}
```

is defined during runtime and can be placed anywhere in your code.

BUT

```
var deposit = function(amt) {
    //do stuff here
}
```

is defined during parse-time.

This means that you should place this at the top of your code, or else, the variable function "deposit" will be undefined at the point of calling.

A working example of your code follows.

```
actbal = (100);
confirm("Would you like to view account balance? Place a deposit? Or make a withdrawl? Press OK to continue!");

do {

    var v = "VIEW";
    var d = "DEP";
    var w = "WITH";

    var cont1 = prompt('Type: "VIEW" , "DEP" , or "WITH" to do their respective comands');

    if (v === cont1.substring(0)) {
        confirm("Your account balance is: " + actbal);

    } else if (d === cont1.substring(0)) {
        var depo = prompt("How much do you want to deposit?");
        var cat = parseFloat(depo);
        if (cat < 0) {
            alert("You cant Deposit a negative number...");
        } else {

            confirm("Your new account balance is: " + deposit(cat));
            //var actbal = actbal + cat;
        }

    } else if (w === cont1.substring(0)) {
        var With = prompt("How much do you want to withdrawl?");
        var dog = parseFloat(With);
        if (dog < 0) {
            alert("You cant Deposit a negative number...");
        } else {

            confirm("Your new account balance is: " + withdrawl(dog));
        }

    } else {
        alert("You have not entered a command correctly!");

    }
}
while (
confirm("Do you want to continue with your account?"));


function deposit (cat) {
    actbal = +actbal + cat;
    return actbal; // DO NOT DOUBLE ADD




};

function withdrawl (dog) {
    actbal = actbal - dog;
    return actbal; // DO NOT DOUBLE SUBTRACT

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful and well explained fix. You also fixed my silly error inside my functions but another user saw it and told me about it. BUT a question, how does the code know that the functions are defined at the bottom if I call them higher in the code? Why does changing the use of variables allow the code to see further along its "trail" than if I say var x=function()... ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's the way javascript is designed. If you define a variable, any variable, let's say `var a = 'dog';` you'll only be able to access this variable **AFTER** it was defined. Same goes with the variable functions. BUT, functions starting with `function name_of_function()` are parsed at runtime, this means **BEFORE** your program starts, the parser reads all of your functions and places it in memory. That's why you can access it anywhere in your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your functions before you call them. If you just re-order them you'll be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/f4109zq9/

```
var withdrawl = function (dog){...}
var deposit = function(cat){ ...}
```

and then your

```
do
{
   ...
}
while(){ .... }
```

Comment: Your fix is correct but what ever code you placed inside that link does not work properly. haha I got my code to work anyway though, so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

First, you're calling the `deposit` and `withdrawl` functions before you define them. If you use the syntax:

```
function deposit() {
    ...
}
```

you can put the definitions anywhere, but when you use an assignment, it only takes effect once the script reaches that line of code.

Second, you're adding and subtracting the balance twice in your functions. You're updating the `actbal` function in the assignment, and then you're adding/subtracting the deposit or withdrawal amount again in your `return` statements. Since you've already updated `actbal`, you should just return it as it is:

```
var deposit = function (cat) {
    actbal = +actbal + cat;
    return actbal;
};

var withdrawl = function (dog) {
    actbal = actbal - dog;
    return actbal;
};
```

Comment: Yea now that I check that I am not sure why that is there. I must have tried some silly fix and kept it without changing it, nice catch. And yea everyone has told me about my misuse/ misplacement of my function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

either use `function  withdrawl()` or write them before you `call`. same for others also. and do not `add or subtract twice` in your functions what you are doing currently.